# Objective-C / Cocoa creation release order?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am just curious if the order expressed for the release of objects should reflect the reverse of their order in the hierarchy:

```
// Psuedo code
alloc OBJ_001;
alloc OBJ_001 > OBJ_002;
alloc OBJ_001 > OBJ_002 > NSSting;

release NSString;
release OBJ_002;
release OBJ_001;
```

I am pretty sure it should (makes sense to me), but have not seen any mention of this in my learning so far.

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. I assume you mean that `OBJ_001` owns `OBJ_002` owns the NSString instance, and you own all three objects (co-owning the NSString with `OBJ_002` and co-owning `OBJ_002` with `OBJ_001`).

Doing it in reverse order:

1. Release NSString instance: Nothing happens, because `OBJ_002` still owns it.
2. Release `OBJ_002`: Nothing happens, because `OBJ_001` still owns it.
3. Release `OBJ_001`: It releases `OBJ_002`, which releases the NSString. All three dealloc.

Doing it in the same order:

1. Release `OBJ_001`: It releases `OBJ_002`, then deallocks. `OBJ_002` still exists because you still own it.
2. Release `OBJ_002`: It releases the NSString, then deallocks. The NSString still exists because you still own it.
3. Release NSString instance: It deallocks.

Either way, all three instances dealloc. There is no difference.

I prefer the reverse order, but that's purely a style choice.

Comment: The one gotcha is if you have order dependencies in your -dealloc methods.  In short, don't have order dependencies in your -dealloc! methods.  Or, better yet, turn on GC and be done with it (if targeting Mac OS X).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say so, as long as you're done using it you can release it whenever you want.